# How to See The Position Of An Index. Like 1-15 Not Coordinates

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

To preface this I really don't understand how well to phrase this other than the title. I'm trying to see which position the Index is on to test whether I can go back or if that will go out of the range. For example something like this. Also I think the index starts at one but I don't know for sure. By the way the spacing in the beginning might be a little confusing but that got moved because of stack overflow not recognizing it as code.

```
if (Index.Position == 0)
{
    CanGoBack = false;
}
else
{
    CanGoBack = true;
}
```

Here is the actual written code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
public class Dialog : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI textDisplay;
    public string[] sentences;
    private int index; 
    public float typingSpeed;
    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject Dialog_Manager;
    public bool NextLine = true;
    public bool CanGoBack = false;

    IEnumerator Type()
    {
        foreach(char letter in sentences[index].ToCharArray())
        {
            textDisplay.text += letter; 
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(typingSpeed);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Wait()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.5f);
        index++;    
        textDisplay.text = "";
        NextLine = true;
        CanGoBack = true;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Type());       
    }

    public void Play()
    {         
        player.SetActive(true);
        Dialog_Manager.SetActive(false);
    }
    
    public void LastSentence()
    {    
        if(index < sentences.Length - 1)
        {     
            index--;    
            textDisplay.text = "";
            StartCoroutine(Type());            
        } 
        else 
        {
            textDisplay.text = "";        
        }                        
    }             

    public void NextSentence()
    {
        if(index < sentences.Length - 1) 
        {
            index++;
            textDisplay.text = "";
            StartCoroutine(Type())
         }       
         else 
         {
             textDisplay.text = "";
         }
     }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {  
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
           NextSentence();         
        } 
       
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {     
            LastSentence();    
        }  
    }                   
}
```

Comment: Index in c# is `0` based so no, it does not start at `1`. It's a bit unclear what exactly you mean since the index already **is** the position in your array ...

Comment: Okay I think I might've figured it out. Every time I move the index I add 1 to an int

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand the difference between index and array. I've never used arrays or Coroutines/IEnumerators. Could You explain the difference?

Comment: The difference between an `index` and an `array`? `Array` has `indexes`. An index is a position in the data structure `array` that ranges from `0` to the `arrays` length - 1. The reason it is the length - 1 is due to the indexes starting at 0. An actual `array` is a data structure that holds data. The data can be accessed by using `indexes`. If you have an array of size 3 that looks like {0, 5, 2}, then accessing array[0] is 0, array[1] is 5, array[2] is 2, and array[4] or array[-1] is going to be out of bounds, as they do not exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
int position = sentences.IndexOf("your string");
```